# Как принять данные в json_decode?

Tags: json

API сервис отправляет мне на одну из страниц моего сайта данные в json.
http://dev.blockcypher.com/?shell#paymentforwardcallback
Помогите разобраться как их прочитать.

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: прочитать где? на клиенте? на сервере?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.